# Rselenium remDR$open() error

Tags: r, selenium

I am running this code:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer(update=T)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
```

And getting this error:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

And despite searching (honest!), I can't find out why this is happening. Any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()`. Also add the output of `system("java -version")`.