# How can I start Rselenium in Mac?

Tags: r, macos, selenium

I am trying to run this simple code.

```
library("RSelenium")
checkForServer()
startServer() #Default server
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open(silent = TRUE) #Opens a browser
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

How can I fix this?

---

## Diagnosis

### sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.3.5 XML_3.98-1.3    RJSONIO_1.3-0   RCurl_1.95-4.7  bitops_1.0-6    dplyr_0.4.3    
[7] rvest_0.3.1     xml2_0.1.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3        assertthat_0.1     R6_2.1.2           DBI_0.3.1          magrittr_1.5      
 [6] httr_1.1.0         curl_0.9.6         tools_3.2.3        parallel_3.2.3     rsconnect_0.4.1.11
[11] caTools_1.17.1
```

### system("java -version")

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Similar question. No solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028834/rselenium-remdropen-error

Comment: Given the comment from the package author on the previous question, it would seem sensible to follow the same advice for this question.

Comment: I have added the information.